# I've forgotten a word: something like "Persona effect"?

Tags: expressions

I learned a word a while back, and I *just* tried to recall it today and use it after like... 10+ years. It's escaped me now.

The meaning of the word or effect or disorder, to the best of my memory, is when people begin to act or behave like their online avatar/persona/alter ego, or something to that effect.

I believe it was about 7 letters + the word "effect" or "disorder". Part of me feels like it may have had a 'g' in it somewhere. I also have a weird feeling that, like "narcissism", it was named after someone, possibly from Greek Mythology as well. I've looked in a thesaurus for clues but nothing rings the bell of familiarity.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: “My guy syndrome?” https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it

Comment: Not quite, but interesting! Thanks!

Comment: Many find trying to find the word in ones mind to be off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

**FOUND**

***"Proteus Effect"***

From Wikipedia:

> The Proteus effect describes a phenomenon in which the behavior of an individual, within virtual worlds, is changed by the characteristics of their avatar.

Nevermind. Thanks website for being here to jog my memory :) <3